# MVC URL rerouting '#' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes, special-characters

I am having some trouble while rerouting some links.

I am updating a website and am looking to reroute old links/bookmarks to the new file locations using MVC 4.

**My error:**

The old system has URLs in the form 'category.aspx#001234'. Where the number references a post in a database. Only when I read this URL in my RouteConfig it will not read anything after the hash.

**Some code:**

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "temp",
            url: "{type}.aspx#{postnumber}",
            defaults: new { controller = "GetPost", action = "GetPostFromNo", type="", postnumber = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

GetPost.GetPostFromNo.cs

```
public ActionResult GetPostFromNo(string type, string postnumber)
    {
        var url = Server.HtmlEncode(type);
        url += " - ";
        url += Server.HtmlEncode(postnumber);

        return Content(url);
    }
```

**Output:**

If I place the hash (category.aspx#001234) on the page I recieve a 404.

But if I remove the hash (category.aspx001234) from my code and from the page URL, my output is as I would expect...

'category - 001234'

**My Question:**

Is there any way for me to see what the number is after the hash?

Comment: Are anchors sent back to the server? because # is used for anchors

Comment: Anchors (`#`) are client-side only. They reference a particular location *within* a page, not an actual URI. You could maybe implement some JavaScript on a particular page that you redirect all of those links to, that will then change `location.href` to the right final URL, but you won't be able to do anything server-side with it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I don't believe it to be an anchor. I think it is a parameter which is used to query a database (unless anchors can do that). [here](http://www.turffiles.ncsu.edu/Alerts.aspx#005585) a link to the actual site to see what is going on

Comment: @user3009729: No offense, but it doesn't really matter what you *believe* it to be. It's an anchor by definition. You could call it a thingy-mabob for all it matters; the point is that it's not sent to the server, thus you cannot redirect based on it.

Comment: @user3009729: Just to elucidate the issue a little more, if you take the anchor portion out of the URL (i.e. just `/Alerts.aspx`, you'll see that it loads the same page, only without the content below the table. If you pay very close attention when you load the version *with* the anchor, you'll see a flash as the bottom portion is initially blank, and then content appears. This is JavaScript, pulling in the content (or display content already on page, but hidden) based on the anchor value. *But*, it's all client-side.

Comment: @ChrisPratt No offense taken. I thank you for your help. And you are correct. That is how they seemed to query the information. Currently I am running down how to get the anchor information in the rerouting.

Comment: You must change the # to  ?